# Remove specific word in a cell based on another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a formula to remove a specific word in a cell, and that the specific word is a reference to another cell?

For example:

- Cell A1: PETER
- Cell B1: BETTY; MARY; PETER; JOHN; SALLY

I Would like to remove the word “PETER“ in Cell B1, but keep the rest of the text because it shows “PETER” in Cell A1

If A1 shows “MARY” then the term “MARY” should be removed from B1, but the rest should remain.

Comment: This would probably require [tag:vba], unless the fields are already dynamically generated.

Comment: If B1 is formula, you cannot say *Cell B1: BETTY; MARY; PETER; JOHN; SALLY*. If it is a literal, it cannot be altered by a formula in another cell.

Comment: If you can show the results in a cell other than `B1`, and if you have Excel 2016+, this can be done with a formula.  If you must somehow change `B1`, you'll need to use VBA.

Comment: I think =SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,"")  formula works for your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

In **C1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1&"; ",""),A1,"")
```

This will handle both an "internal" PETER or a "trailing" PETER.

[image]

If you want to do this "in-place" *(without using a separate cell)*, then run this short macro:

```
Sub DropName()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    s1 = [A1]
    s2 = [B1]
    s2 = Replace(s2, "; " & s1, "")
    s2 = Replace(s2, s1, "")
    [B1] = s2
End Sub
```

Comment: *This will handle both an "internal" PETER or a "trailing" PETER.* ... and while set column B hidden you will SEE the result similar to needed one.

Comment: If the name in `A1` is a **part** of a name in `B1`, that portion of the name will be removed. Maybe not what the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use this **array formula**:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B1,";",CHAR(1))),CHAR(1),"</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[not(text()='"&A1&"')]"))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar.

The formula

- creates an XML document
- uses `FILTERXML` to return all the nodes that are not equal to `PETER`.
- `TEXTJOIN` then puts those nodes back together.

[image]